# How to highlight option just like a normal "click" event and not just add attr "selected"

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

https://jsfiddle.net/silenthunter206/96ukznye/

I have input select with ID="COUNTRYID" and the value of "LOCAL" is retrieved when i click on certain cards using JQUERY. Before I explain, my logic is already correct. But JQUERY part isn't.

When LOCAL is '1' it will disabled all the OPTION first, then find OPTION ID="MY" and only enable this one.

And when LOCAL is not '1' all the OPTION are enabled.

**My problem:**

When LOCAL is '1' i cannot and should not be able to click other options except OPTION ID="MY" and it works as expected and i force it to be "selected" using JQUERY.

But when i click on other cards and LOCAL is not 1, and I click on OPTION ID="US" **then i click again on the cards which LOCAL is 1**, the 
highlighted row remains on ID="US". My next problem is when i submit form, the ID="US" is submitted instead of ID="MY" eventhough all the options except ID="MY" are enabled and i explicitly set attribute OPTION ID="MY" as selected

**How to highlight the option like an actual click event instead of just adding attr selected to option?**

I have tried keydown(), keyup(), and focus() and click() but none is hightlighting the option that has attr "selected"

```
if(LOCAL =='1'){
    $('#COUNTRYID > option').each(function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    })
    $("#COUNTRYID option[id=MY]").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#COUNTRYID option[id=MY]").attr("selected","selected");

}else{
  $('#COUNTRYID > option').each(function(){
  var ID = $(this).attr("id");
  if(ID == 'COUNTRYIDLABEL'){
  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }else{
  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
  }

  });
  $("#COUNTRYID option[id=MY]").attr("selected","selected");

}
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for your problem?

Comment: @SmitRaval https://jsfiddle.net/silenthunter206/96ukznye/

Comment: @SmitRaval Did you check my fiddle code?